# How can I check if a request is made to the cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I use a MVC application that use "outputcache" attribute:

```
namespace CachingInMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam ="none", Location = 
        OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i know/check if "index" works on cache or on server?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that in two ways:

- Set a breakpoint in the action. And if you refresh the browser and it does not hit the breakpoint then it is being served from cache
- Or open the web developer tool on firefox. Under the *Network* section check the value in the *Transferred* column. If it says *cached* then it was picked from the cache

[image]